# Passing multiple vaules via rails radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a method in my controller which creates a association record:

```
def updating_rating
      rr = ProductRecommendation.new(:rating_id => rating_set.id, :recommendation_id => r.id)
      rr.save!
  end
```

My routes are set up as:

```
match "/recommendations/updating_rating" => "recommendation#updating_rating", :as => 'update'
```

And in my view I have:

```
<div>
<%= form_tag(update_url, :method => :post) do  %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:rating_id, '1', :recommendation_id => rec.recommendation.id) %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:rating_id, '2', :recommendation_id => rec.recommendation.id) %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:rating_id, '3', :recommendation_id => rec.recommendation.id) %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

This only passes the rating_id as a value. How can I pass both the rating_id + the recommendation_id to my controller method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hidden field:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :recommendation_id => rec.recommendation.id %>
```

and then fetch the `:recommendation_id` in your controller with something like:

```
params[:recommendation_id]
```